# Expanded Usercard, See Vote Counts help page needs an overhaul

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Back in the day, when StackExchange was just StackOverflow with a simple white background, [images depicting how to use the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) with opaque white backgrounds might have been acceptable.  These days, however, graduated sites are all themed, each with custom graphics and buttons and backgrounds.

For example, this screenshot was taken [from EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> [image]

Right off the bat, I notice several things wrong:

1. The image boundaries are painfully obvious.
2. Voting buttons in the depiction do not match the site's theme.
3. The example usercard shows stats from a different site.  Even more obvious when the badge count icons do not look the same.
4. There are pixel "growths" on the "Normal" and "Expanded" headings.  What graphics program rendered those, seriously?

Meanwhile, the tour page is delightful and custom for each site, and is exactly what the privileges pages should also look like and behave.

Let's show the privileges pages a little love, shall we?

P.S. I think it would be really cool if the page could grab the user's mouse cursor and demonstrate how to see vote counts.